# regular expression in without loop

Tags: java, regex

How can I rewrite the following expression without using a loop?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(filterRegEx);
Matcher regexMatcher = pattern.matcher("(.*)");

for (String word : words) {
    if (pattern.matcher(word).matches()) {
        foundList.add(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do what exactly you are doing right now? `matcher()` method takes a string with which you want to match the regex with. You are passing a regex pattern right now. May be explain in words what you exactly want.

Comment: Did you intend to use `regexMatcher` somewhere or is it irrelevant?

Comment: Are you sure about that Matcher? Seems to match the whole String.

Comment: what is thar regex for? is it to match the entire word ? if u trying to match words inside `()` then use `\(.*\)`

Comment: Sorry about the (.*), i am just practicing. I read somewhere that i can perform a match using the pattern class without utilising a for loop (it would do it for me) but i am unable to find any examples. Hence me asking the question. The code above does work but just want to find other ways of doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use some form of functional programming if you want to avoid using a loop. Java 8 will have some new features in this area, but right now you can use the [`Collections2#filter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) (or `Iterables#filter`) method from Google Guava; it lets you specify a condition (such as `pattern.matcher(word).matches()`) and selects the elements in the collection that match.

Note that the object returned "read through" to the original collection, so you'd need to make a copy of them (such as with [`ArrayList(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29)) if you need to keep the filtered list around.